# Possible anomaly in Cryptonomicon

Tags: literature

Toward the beginning of Neal Stephenson's Cryptonomicon, Avi gives Randy two strings of sixteen supposedly random hexadecimal numbers as encryption keys:

```
AF  10  06  E9  99  BA  11  07  64  C1  89  E3  40  8C  72  55
67  81  A4  AE  FF  40  25  9B  43  0E  29  8D  56  60  E3  2F
```

If you change the hexadecimals to decimals and change the decimals to letters, modulo 25 without J, like Lawrence does with his one-time-pads later in the book, you get:

```
z   k   f   h   c   l   r   g   z   s   m   b   o   p   o   k
c   d   o   y   m   o   m   e   r   o   q   q   l   v   b   w
```

The first sequence contains two Os and the second contains three Os. The probability of randomly picking at least five Os out of twenty-five letters given thirty-two picks is less than 1%, which makes it seem like the numbers are not actually random.

Additionally, there are six prime numbers in each sequence:

```
E9  11  07  C1  89  E3
67  25  43  29  E3  2F
```

(all primes in base sixteen)

What does this mean?

Comment: Shouldn't this go [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 9 primes between 0 and 25, so having six primes when picking sixteen numbers at random in this interval perfectly makes sense. In addition, this is just an encoding of the letters: we could have associated the letters to numbers between 1 and 26, or 8 and 33... So checking for primality has no reason to be relevant here.

Moreover, the probability of having five O's might be low, but this is just one letter; have you looked at the probability that "some" letter appears five times? It should be quite reasonable. To me, you are seeing patterns where there is nothing to search for: given a small enough random sequence, one can always find many such patterns.

It took me three attempts on this [random sequence of letters generator](http://www.dave-reed.com/Nifty/randSeq.html) to get the sequence pmrvkpehkyonfrkhxrnpnznbmnfmluwh, which contains five n's.